# Birt: Formatting chart tooltip and adding aggregation to a chart tooltip?

Tags: birt

I have three questions regarding Birt Tooltip

1) How do I format the number in the default tooltip (If I am not adding anything to the tooltip text). I tried to change the format of tooltip of Y Value Series but I realized that only works if I have put an expression in the tooltip of the Y Value series. I have not edited the tooltip of Y Value series, the chart will show the default data label instead and I am not sure how to format the default tooltip

2) I have plotted sum(revenue) on Y axis and months on x axis. I wanted a custom tooltip so I edited the tooltip expression of the Y Value series in chart. What I found was that the default tooltip was showing correct value but If I put the same expression row["revenue"] in the tooltip, the tooltip shows a data value that is much less than sum(revenue) that is plotted in the bar. I believe that this is because the tootltip is not aggregating the revenue? If Yes, then how do I put the sum(revenue) in the expression?

3) I wanted to add another information (count of units sold) so I created an aggregation count(unitssold). I called this cnt_unit_sold and added this to the tooltip of chart. The problem is that if I put my mouse over a month bar, the tooltip shows aggregated count for all months rather than that specific month. How can I add grouping to the aggregation so that it shows the aggregated count for each month rather than for all months

Regards
Arif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so in case if someone has not found an answer to this question, here is the answer. In order to add aggregation to the tooltip, you need to create aggregate outside the chart's contains (for example create aggregation inside a grid). Then you can use that aggregation in the tooltip

Arif

Answer (score 0):

I someone is still trying to achieve this, now you can use "valueData" instead.

```
    row["dim1"]+" for "+row["period"]+" : "+valueData
```

in my example (the code goes in the tooltip expression) I asm using a stacked barchart, dim1 is the series used to stack values and period is the X series. Valuedata is the Y value (aggregated)